# How to hide menu in Windows Mobile 6.5 with win32 c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-mobile

How to hide menu bar ( the one with start button ) in Windows Mobile 6.5 with win32 c++, I mean show full screen?
Can't find a proper answer to that... Long time googleing, so far unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

To make a window on weh 6.5 3 really fullscreen, you have to set the menu of the window to NULL and resize the window.

```
#ifdef USEMENUBAR
    nclog(L"iLock5: InitInstance: USEMENUBAR...\r\n");
    if(UseMenuBar==1){
            // When the main window is created using CW_USEDEFAULT the height of the menubar (if one
            // is created is not taken into account). So we resize the window after creating it
            // if a menubar is present
            if (g_hWndMenuBar)
            {
                    nclog(L"iLock5: InitInstance: Moving window because of UseMenuBar\r\n");
                    RECT rc;
                    RECT rcMenuBar;

                    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);
                    GetWindowRect(g_hWndMenuBar, &rcMenuBar);
                    rc.bottom -= (rcMenuBar.bottom - rcMenuBar.top);

                    MoveWindow(hWnd, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right-rc.left, rc.bottom-rc.top, FALSE);
            }
    }
#else
    nclog(L"iLock5: InitInstance: USEMENUBAR undefined...\r\n");
    if(UseMenuBar==0){
            nclog(L"iLock5: InitInstance: Moving window without MenuBar\r\n");
            //move window to upper left logical corner
            MoveWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, theRect.right, theRect.bottom, FALSE);
    }
#endif
```

This is of my iLock kiosk mode starter tool at http://code.google.com/p/ilock5/source/browse/trunk/iLock5/iLock5.cpp. Article at http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/03/18/ilock-a-tool-to-lock-the-startup-process-of-a-windows-mobile-device/